# Hanukkah Glass Menorah Drip Tray with Brachos on it

Tags: halacha, chanuka, shemos-sacred-names, candle-lighting

Would it be mutar to place the menorah on a Hanukkah Glass Menorah Drip Tray [https://www.amazon.com/Rite-Lite-Tempered-Glass-Menorah/dp/B00PBFBUOO](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00PBFBUOO) even if the drip tray has brachos on it, or would this be not proper because you are placing an object on the words of brachos and the wax will fall on them?